# ProgressDialog in runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progressdialog

I am trying to show progress dialog and update it inside runOnUiThread
but the progress bar never shown. when I replace the runOnUiThread with "new Thread" it work fine. But I want it to work with runOnUiThread

here is my code , I have deleted unnecessary codes

```
public class test extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog progress;
Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
testing();
}

public void testing() {
    progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Saving Progress");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.setMax(100);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //do some work 
        for (int i =0; i<100;i++){

        //some work


             progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progress.setProgress(finalCount);
                        }
             });
        }
}
}
```

Comment: It will never work ... UI implementation basics: if you block UI thread with the loop any other UI calls (like setting progress) will not called until you release the UI thread - because message queue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog progress;
Handler workHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Saving Progress");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.setMax(100);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();

    workHandler = new Handler(new HandlerThread("workHandlerThread").getLooper());

    workHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Do some work


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progress.setProgress(/*work result*/);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

The idea is you do the work on the HandlerThread bound to `workHandler`, and post the results back the the UI using `runOnUiThread()`